# Android Studio Launch Error

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to launch Android Studio but I get the following error:

> "The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the value of C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin) does not point to a valid JVM installation."

Yet I know it does. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: It seems java 8 is not supported. Install java 7 and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `\bin` from your enviroment variable `JAVA_HOME`

If this fails, retry with a 64-bit jdk. You have a 32-bit (x86) currently installed.

[JDK Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comment: Trying without the `\bin` gives another, similar error. I am using the 32-bit JDK, will this not suffice?

Comment: I can only say, that my Java 8 64-jdk works with android studio and I have no \bin in my JAVA_HOME.

Comment: remember to close and restart applications after you modified enviroment variables, since they may get only loaded at startup.

Comment: I guess I'll have to install the 64-bit edition as well then.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system properties then Advanced system settings Cick bellow Enviroment variables in system variables click New and input variable name JAVA_HOME and variable value java path, (example: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0)

Answer (score 0):

go to this path

> Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Environment
>   Variables.

Create new system path named as `JAVA_HOME` 
 path will be

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141

save it.