# Failure to launch Android Studio; Failed to create JVM: error code -1

Tags: java, android, jvm

When trying to launch Android Studio on Windows I get the following error:

Failed to create JVM: error code -1
JVM Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre

I have tried setting the JAVA_PATH variable and I have also tried uninstalling Android Studio and Java and then reinstalling. I came to this error while trying to mess with the path variables to use an external Java library.

Any suggestions on fixing this problem?

EDIT: The solution I gave below seems to work for error code -1 and -4 in my case. The only issue is that you lose your user settings if you use the solution given.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Launch Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679621/android-studio-launch-error)

Comment: I have tried what was suggested in that post. I have removed /bin and I have a 64 bit version of Java on a 64 bit architecture

Comment: Does the versions of the JDK and JRE match? (e.g. JRE 1.8 and JDK 1.8)

Comment: Yes. jdk 1.8.0_91 and jre 1.8.0_91

Comment: Yes JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

Comment: edit JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin and then give a try

Comment: I have [answered on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532284/5376073) what was working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!
This thread was extremely helpful:

[failed to create jvm error code 4 android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094132/failed-to-create-jvm-error-code-4-android-studio)

What ended up working for me was deleting the Android Studio setting folder in my user folder.

C:\Users\my_username.AndroidStudio

Then re-open Android Studio then everything work fine for me.

Comment: This is the only thing that helped me.  Of note is that I had to reinstall Android studio after doing this, but at least it let me continue after doing that (where before, it did not).

Answer (score 3):

With: Failed to create JVM: error code -1

I tried deleting the *studio64.exe.vmoptions* file

(from: *C:\Users\vungnho.AndroidStudio3.1\config*)

(*vungnho* - my user name;  *.AndroidStudio3.1* - config folder for current Studio)

and it worked!

---

Exactly, I tried reinstall Android Studio but the problem still occur,

so I tried rename *.AndroidStudio3.1* folder, but it have many my configs :(

Answer (score 0):

For those that are using the Android studio version 4, can find the .vmoptions in the following path:  C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

as mentioned here in the official documentation of Android: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config