# strange error after setting variables JAVA_HOME and JVM path

Tags: android, android-studio, jvm, java-home, setting

I hope you can help me, please. 
I'm trying to run android studio in my pc but this message come up 
[image: Error jvm]

i've set JAVA_HOME variable with bin and without it, also PATH but nothing works out. I verified the version of java installed in my pc and it is 1.8.0_111-b14, then I noticed that JDK file was missing so i downloaded it from oracle, then i changed the value of all variables, but i did not work out neither. the current values of Java_home and path are these
  [image: Settings]

and the file of jre and jdk in my pc are these

jdk1.8.0_101
jdk1.8.0_111
jre1.8.0_101
jre1.8.0_111

eclipse runs perfectly

thanks to all of you guys in advance

Comment: Did you try solutions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084217/failure-to-launch-android-studio-failed-to-create-jvm-error-code-1 ?

Comment: yes :( and there is no user.androidstudio file

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Java JDK not just a JRE. You can get one at Oracle's Java Page

Edit: From the Maven Properties Guide:

${java.home} specifies the path to the current JRE_HOME environment use with relative paths to get for example:
${java.home}../bin/java.exe

Comment: i already did it, that's the strange part. I don't know why it doesn't work